# Logic problem in TOEFL book

Tags: logic

I came across the text about weather system

[image: text]![]

So I think the passage infers that

1. every *chaotic system* is subset of *nonlinear equations*
2. *weather systems* are subset of *nonlinear equations*
3. *chaotic systems* and *nonlinear equations* aren't the same subset

I can think of 3 possibilities in this case

[image: diagram]

But I couldn't answer this question

[image: question]

I looked up the solutions manual and it says the answer is **C**. I rejected **C** as soon as I saw it because it reminds me that this kind of implication is not correct:

> if A then B → if B then A

Can anyone explain why **C** is correct?

Comment: Natural languages are elusive and make heavy use of hidden assumptions, contrarily to logic. Here, implicit in the text is that economy and weather are given examples of chaotic systems (because this is the topic of the paragraph and we would not expect the author to give unrelated examples). The question then assumes this implicit understanding.

Comment: The formulation "weather is nonlinear..." is misleading: a more explicit formulation would be "weather, an example of chaotic system, indeed display the non-linear characteristic just given"

Comment: In your formulation, you'd have "2. Weather systems are a subset of chaotic systems, *therefore* they are a subset of non-linear equations."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You are correct.  The book is sloppy with its wordings**

Your passages 1 and 3 are important, and (almost) correct

1. Every chaotic system is based on nonlinear equations
2. There are systems based on nonlinear equations which are not chaotic

From these, we can infer that there are chaotic systems are a *proper* subset of systems defined by nonlinear equations.  Weather is explained as being nonlinear, but that's as far as you can go.

However there are a few fun issues:

- Not all chaotic systems are based on nonlinear equations;  *most* are.  Infinitely dimensional linear systems can be chaotic.  However, the book is right that, within the realm of finite dimensional systems, if you're linear, you're not chaotic
- Weather is not nonlinear because of the reasons they say.  Weather is nonlinear because the models we have for it are non-linear differential equations.  The effects of changes in windspeed are an effect of the nonlinearity, not a cause of it.

For completeness, here are the "characteristics of Chaotic systems" from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory), which openly states that they are not fully agreed upon, but these are pretty good starting points:

1. It must be sensitive to initial conditions;
2. It must be topologically mixing; and
3. It must have dense periodic orbits.

The actual reason weather is considered chaotic is that it demonstrates all three of these characteristics.

Comment: I get your idea. But based only on the information in the book can we say that _weather is chaotic_? And if we can say so, isn't the answer __C__ incorrect?!

Comment: Your frustrations are well founded.  Based on the information in the book, and the standard rules of logic, we cannot say weather is chaotic.  And even if we could say weather is chaotic, it is not merely because it is described by nonlinear equations.

Comment: If it helps any, it is trivial to build a nonlinear system which is not chaotic.  First create a damped spring oscillator system, which is a classic linear ODE.  Its linear, so non chaotic.  Now perturb a derivative by (sin(x)/2)^1000.  This perturbation can clearly be no more than 1/2^1000, so its effects will be easily damped by a reasonable damping coefficient, ensuring the system is still not chaotic, even though it is nonlinear.

Comment: In the text, the effects of windspped changes are not intented to be *causes* of non-linearity but a *proof* of it, or at least an indicator (it's a logical or inferential "because" not a causal or explanatory one).

Comment: See my comments above: natural languages are elusive, you should not expect crystal clear reasonning in popularization textbooks.

Comment: Weather is implicitely given as an example of chatic system. One must adopt a principle of charity when reading such texts (fill the gaps).

Comment: @quen_tin: You are correct that natural languages are elusive.  However, this does not change the actual question the OP is asking.  The OP is being given a question whose answer is not actually backed up by the text, and which is actually *wrong* in that it does not make a truthful statement.  I think you could make an argument that it is possible to use the flexibility of natural language to corrupt the wording of the question into something which is false, but matches a potential corruption of the textbook.  At some point, though, you have to wonder if you accidentally started a religion.

Comment: Another view might be to argue that multiple choice, itself, is to blame.  Multiple choice forces readers to use one of 4 canned responses, and prevents them from correcting mistakes in those repsonses.  However, that is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: I agree that the formulation of the "good" answer is somehow misleading, but I wouldn't say wrong. My charitable reading would be an inferential because (non-linearity is an indicator of being chaotic). I agree that's not very rigorous. Now of course you can always corrupt the text but there are natural readings.

Comment: At the basis of the principle of charity is: expect your interlocutor to mean something (he believes to be) true.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting comments. I think that _principle of charity_ can be used in an informal conversation while questions like that one have to be based on strict logical reasoning